# Pandas: Drop Columns that are equal to weekend

Tags: python, pandas, weekend

I have a probably rather simple question. I have a  daily df for 10 years consisting of columns that have data and are named according to the day:

```
2017-04-07      2017-04-08     2017-04-09  
   a                a                a
```

I now want to drop every column which name, i.e. which day, is equal to a weekend. For example, in the above example only this would remain:

```
2017-04-07       
   a
```

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`weekday`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) + [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) for mask  with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for select all columns which are not (`~`) weekdays:

```
print (df)
  2017-04-07 2017-04-08 2017-04-09 2017-04-10
0          a          a          a          a

#if necessary
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

print (~df.columns.weekday.isin([5,6]))
[ True False False  True]

print (df.loc[:, ~df.columns.weekday.isin([5,6])])
  2017-04-07 2017-04-10
0          a          a
```

Another solution:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
print (df[df.columns[~df.columns.weekday.isin([5,6])]])
  2017-04-07 2017-04-10
0          a          a
```

For older verison of pandas use:

```
print (df[df.columns[~pd.Series(df.columns.weekday).isin([5,6])]])
  2017-04-07 2017-04-10
0          a          a
```

Or:

```
print (df[df.columns[np.in1d(df.columns.weekday, [5,6])]])
  2017-04-08 2017-04-09
0          a          a
```

Comment: Thanks ! It looks good. I get the following error: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'

Comment: There is problem dont use last version of pandas, get me a sec.

Comment: sorry, but now I get this error: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'weekday'

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ? It return `DataTimeindex` ?

Comment: If nott, first convert columns names to `Datetime` by `df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)`

Comment: yep. I forgot that. Works perfectly. Thank you so much.